# Ajax return call for error is not returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call inside a function like so:

```
function send_data(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            //Empty for now
        },

        error: function (xhr) {
            return xhr.responseJSON;
        },

    });
}
```

and then I trigger this function like so:

```
console.log(send_data(url, data));
```

I should receive the response output, but I don't. I instead, get undefined. I know JavaScript is asynchronous, but shouldn't this work? I added a `console.log` output inside the error function, before the return statement, and it outputs the data correctly. So why doesn't it return the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you do is basically declare function inside function

```js
function foo(){
  function bar(){console.log('in bar')}
}

console.log(foo())
```

as you can see, the `bar` is not called (which in your case would be called by `jQuery`)

Comment: I see, what is the best way of fixing this?

Comment: the basic would be `return $.ajax(...)`, but you should learn about `Promise` to make use of it.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Is there a way to handle 400 bad request errors? I'm getting a bad request because let's say not all the form elements are used. so a bad request will be thrown. Is there a way to handle them?

Comment: @user2896120 I don't use jQuery, but isn't the `error` callback just for this?

Comment: So is it normal for the console to output 400 bad request each time? I was wondering if I could hide that

Comment: @user2896120 I'd guess it's because you're trying to get `responseJSON` when it's `400`. The `responseJSON` should not even exist.

Comment: But if the form was submitted incorrectly, i.e password did not meet requirements, wouldn't the 400 bad request entail a responseJSON indicating what the password error is?

Comment: @user2896120 I'm not sure what your API looks like, can you provide [mcve]?

Comment: Hmm, I'm using Django's built in REST API. There's a registration endpoint that I submit a POST request to with all the registration details (username, email, password). If there's an error in any of these details submitted (empty fields, incorrect format, etc.) then a 400 bad request will be thrown with a JSON response indicating why each field failed. If there are no errors, a successful 200 response will be received.

Comment: @user2896120 then it should be fine O.o. Can you click on the console to check is it really a `exception` or just a `console.error()` by `jQuery`?

Comment: `jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/ 400 (Bad Request)` so i'm guessing it's just an error by jquery